# Оценка HTML-верстальщика

Tags: html, вёрстка

Как можно оценить верстальщика и его работу (по уровню профессиональности)? Для некоторых - сайт не расползается значит все хорошо, а другие требуют соответствие стандартам - в итоге сайт убит для "некоторых" браузеров. Т.е. на какие критерии смотреть или тестовые задания давать?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

У каждого они (критерии) свои и многое зависит от проекта. Но основные моменты, которые важны именно нам:

1. Для нас важно, чтобы было сверстано «пиксель в пиксель» с макетом. Все отступы, размеры, шрифты, цвета. Т.к. дизайнер заморачивается с сеткой и высчитывает все отступы, чтобы все было гармонично не только на глаз, но и математически (гуглите сетка в дизайне, золотое сечение). Дизайнер тратит на это много времени и херить все на верстке очень плохо.

Поэтому мы требуем при верстке идеальное сочетание в плагине pixel perfect. Незначительные отклонения все же будут, без них нельзя (в 1-2 пикселя допускаем), т.к. каждый браузер и ос по разному рендерят шрифты, но все же требуем по максимуму соответствия и сильно пинаем за это и уделяем этому время. Особенно беспокоится дизайнер.

Если 1 в 1 сверстать нельзя, то важно, чтобы основные элементы были на одном уровне с другими (на одной линии) и т.д.
Т.е. конкретно для нас в нашей студии (да в любой нормальной) важна сетка, размеры, интервалы. Это первое.

2. Второе, что важно нам, чтобы по максимуму все было в css, а не в html файле. Цель — как можно меньше тегов в html и атрибуов к ним. (при этом не стоит забывать про валидность).
3. Чтобы по максимуму (скрипты и css) были в отдельных файлах, а не в теле документа. Чтобы все было красиво.
4. Красивый код, проставленные интервалы, комментарии, табуляции.
5. Только блочная верстка. Там, где можно обойтись без таблиц, их быть не должно.
6. Кроссбраузерность. Мы не бьем ногами, если в ие6 что-то поползло, но если человек знает какой-нибудь хак, пусть даже это костыль, но дает результат — он великолепен.
7. Валидность, безусловно, тоже важна, но лично для нас важен результат, как и что выглядит и работает. Если где-то код не валидный, но делает то, что должен, мы закрываем на это глаза. Конечно, если проект сложный и изменения в верстке потянут много изменений в другом. Если сделать код валидным не составляет труда — мы делаем.

В общем и дизайнер и верстальщик должны быть дотошны до пикселя, любить свою работу. Не спешить, но и не тормозить зря. Главное качество и результат.
Скорость не так важна, однако дедлайны важно не нарушать.
Чтобы их не нарушать, надо хорошо, подробно и четко прописывать ТЗ и оценивать время с запасом. (лучше умножать его на 2-3)

Это то, что касается конкретно меня и нашей студии.

Comment: Хороший ответ, всем пунктам +. Но вот что все так на таблички наезжают? Хоть бы кто объяснил, чем вам таблицы не угодили!? Похоже на сектантство какое-то, таблички зло и все тут)))
Смешно и горько смотреть как верстальщики, лепят десятки вложенных дивов, навешивают кучу хаков, чтобы не дай бог не написать один раз <table>...</table> Так чем же все-таки так плохи таблицы?
PS Я не верстальщик, но порой приходится возится с версткой. Так что буду очень признателен если просветите)))

Comment: Во-первых это таблицы как раз неудобный в плане кода инструмент. Огромное количество тегов + страшный геморрой в случае, если тебе надо столбец, скажем, удалить из середины. Крайне неудобный код в плане поддержки. Во-вторых технические особенности типа "не отобразится пока все содержимое не прогрузится". Может с современными интернетами на первый взгля это кажется не критично, но есть еще как минимум мобильный рынок. Да и если весь сайт поместить в <table>, то можно и секунды потерять и отказаться от оптимизации.

Comment: Но от части я с вами согласен. Иногда особенности таблиц типа возможность пропорционально расчитать расстояние, или организовать выравнивание - единственный выход. Но в этом случае можно обойтись стандартными тегами, например ul / li для организации меню и придать им табличное поведение в CSS при помощи display: table; / table-cell.